# Imprimir determinadas filas pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo un dataframe similar al siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero mostrar aquellas **columnas que alguna de sus filas** contengan un NaN, NaT o None. Si aplico el siguiente código veo cuales son:

```
def null(x):
    return any(pd.isnull(x))

print df.apply(null)
```

Me da algo similar a esto:

```
col1          False
col2          True
col3          False
col4          False
col5          False
col6          True
dtype: bool
```

Se que las que lo contienen son aquellas que tienen un `True`.

**Pero** ahora me salen un listado de tocas las columnas, unas con valor `True` y otras con valor `False`. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que solo salgan las columnas que son `True`? Yo he probado lo siguiente, pero entonces solo me salen los resultado `True` pero sin el nombre de la columna al lado, intuyo que debo estar cerca pero no lo consigo.

```
def null(x):
    if any(pd.isnull(x)) == True:
        print any(pd.isnull(x))

print df.apply(null)
```

Esto me imprime lo siguiente,

```
True
True
```

**EJEMPLO de lo que quiero**

```
col2          True
col6          True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Lo he editado con un ejemplo :D

Comment: Si lo que muestras en "ejemplo de lo que ahora tengo" lo guardas en una variable, digamos `aux`, y la columna con los boolenos se llama por ejemplo `x`, te bastaría hacer `aux[aux.x]` para mostrar sólo los que tienen `True`. Pero la verdad que sigo sin entender del todo el caso. ¿No podrías poner un ejemplo del dataframe de entrada, el que tiene los Nan y múltiples columnas?

Comment: Vuelto a editar @abulafia

Comment: Es que es un dataframe con mil y pico muestras (y muchas más columnas) y los NaN/NaT/None deben estar más abajo.

Comment: Que tienen lo sé porque si le paso `isnull()` me sale True, la cosa era que se me ocurrió solo mostrar esas para prácticar y me di cuenta que no se hacerlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya casi lo tenías. El primer filtro te devolvía una serie cuyo índice eran los nombres de las columnas (todas) y sus valores una serie de booleanos. Basta usar el operador de indexación (`[]`) para quedarse con aquellas filas que tengan valor `True`.

De la misma forma que puedes hacer `df[df.x>3]` por ejemplo, que te selecciona las filas en las la columna `x` del dataframe `df` tienen valor mayor de 3, también puedes hacer `df[df.y]`, que te selecciona las filas del dataframe `df` en las que la columna `y` tiene el valor `True`.

En tu caso el "dataframe" es una Serie, la que te resulta del primer filtro. En lugar de imprimirlo, guardémoslo en una variable, `r`:

```
def null(x):
    return any(pd.isnull(x))

r = df.apply(null)
```

Ahora basta hacer:

```
print r[r]
```

y obtendrás la salida que esperabas:

```
Col2    True
Col6    True
dtype: bool
```

### Aún más sencillo

No necesitas la función `null()` ni `.apply()`:

```
r = df.isnull().any()
print r[r]
```

Y si realmente lo que buscabas son los nombres de las columnas que contuvieran algún nulo, el `print`  final puedes cambiarlo por este otro:

```
print list(r[r].index)
```

```
['Col2', 'Col6']
```

### Addendum

Para reproducibilidad de mis resultados, el dataframe `df` con que trabajaba lo creé de la siguiente forma (no es igual que el tuyo, pero al final sirve para ilustrar el método):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creo 6 columnas de números aleatorios. 20 datos por columna
# Lo guardo en un diccionario cuyas claves son los nombres de columna
data = {}
for i in range(1,7):
  data["Col{}".format(i)] = np.random.randint(20,100, 20)

# Lo convierto en dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Pongo algunos `nan` en algunas celdas de las columnas Col2 y Col6
df.loc[3, "Col2"] = np.nan
df.loc[6, "Col2"] = np.nan
df.loc[7, "Col6"] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes 2 print`s. uno que muestra cuando es True y otro que muestra lo que es fuera de la función. Si lo que quieres es que solo muestre los True, nada más deberias usar el if == True y printear. Si lo que quieres es que no printee los false, elimina el print que tienes fuera o le colocas un if para que solo ejecute la linea print cuando sea true.

Comment: Eso ya lo probé y no funciona